# Symfony Routing dont run Controller

Tags: php, symfony, routes

i'm using

```
"symfony/routing" : "^4.3",
        "symfony/yaml" : "^4.3",
        "symfony/config" : "^4.3",
        "symfony/http-foundation" : "^4.3"
```

i'm entring to the site (localhost:80/foo) and page is blank :/ like controller have never been runned. Whats wrong here ?

Here's my router class - working good

```php
namespace low\controller;


class Router{

    function __construct() {

        $routes = new RouteCollection();

        $filelocator = new FileLocator([__DIR__]);
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($filelocator);
        $routes = $loader->load(__DIR__ . "/../config/routes.yaml");

        // Init RequestContext object
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $context->fromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals());

        // Init UrlMatcher object
        $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
        $parameters = $matcher->match($context->getPathInfo());
    }
}
```

Router yaml file

```
home:
    path:       /
    controller: low\controller\MyController::fooAction
foo:
    path:       /foo
    controller: low\controller\MyController::fooAction
    methods:    GET
```

And my controller

```php
namespace low\controller;

class MyController{

    function fooAction(){
            echo 'anything';
            die();
    }

}
```

I tried composer dumpautoload -o ect

Comment: your function `fooAction` does not return anything. Have a read here about controllers: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Comment: What is tying your router to the controller?  I'm assuming you are not using the actual framework?

Comment: I have the feeling you should show us the index.php or whatever your entry point is. since you're not using the symfony framework, you would have to write that yourself. your Router is weird, not setting instance properties, also not calling the controller (which would also be weird in the constructor)